# iPhone - iOS4 - is there a Step-by-step guide on how to upgrade OLD Apps to new SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios4, upgrade

Is there a Step-by-step guide on how to upgrade OLD Apps to new SDK ?
Especially, which features from old version will not work in new one?

Creating this guide will help companies create toolkit for people who are struggling

Comment: I think it is really hard. If you want for a specific like iOS 4

Answer (score 0):

There's no official step-by-step guide, there are however documents on developer.apple.com showing the API Differences between specific versions of the SDK.

Example: [iOS 4.0 to iOS 4.1 API Differences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS41APIDiffs/index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010179)

Besides reading & examining the changelogs yourself, you can always open your project with the new SDK. If I'm not mistaken will the compiler show warnings for deprecated API calls. After you have fixed these warnings and the project compiles without errors/warnings you should be all set and your app should run on the newer SDK version.

Remember that this could potentially break your app on older SDK versions.